# how do i linking my <script> to my HTML Quiz?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

So I am developing a Quiz Application in JavaScript using Java, CSS and HTML. I need all the code on the same Document (Notepad++) and the JavaScript isn't linking to the HTML Id.
Can someone help?

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Quiz</title>
</head>
<style>
  body {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
  }
  
  .grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #cbcbcb;
    box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #cbcbcb
  }
  
  .grid h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #57636e;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2px 0px border-radius: 50px
  }
  
  .grid #question {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #5a6772
  }
  
  .buttons {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  
  #btn0,
  #btn1,
  #btn2,
  #btn3 {
    background-color: #778897;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #1d3c6a;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 10px 40px 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
  }
  
  #progress {
    color: #2b2b2b;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  
  #btn0:hover,
  #btn1:hover,
  #btn2:hover,
  #btn3:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #57636e;
  }
  
  #btn0:focus,
  #btn1:focus,
  #btn2:focus,
  #btn3:focus {
    outline: 0;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div id="quiz">
      <h1>Quiz</h1>
      <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px">

      <p id="question"></p>

      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
        <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
        <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
        <button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
      </div>

      <hr style="margin-top: 50px">
      <footer>
        <p id="progress">Question x of y.</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script language="javascript">
    function Quiz(questions) {
      this.score = 0;
      this.questions = questions;
      this.questionIndex = 0;
    }
    Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
      return this.questions(this.questionIndex);
    }
    Quiz.prototype.isIndex = function() {
      return this.questions.length === this.questionIndex;
    }
    Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
      this.questionIndex++;
      if (this.getQuestionIndex().correctAnswer(answer)) {
        this.score++;
      }
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    //Questions.js
    function Question(text, choices, answer) {
      this.text = text;
      this.choices = choices;
      this.answer = answer;
    }
    Question.prototype.correctAnswer = function(choice) {
      return choice === this.answer;
    }
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    //Apps
    function populate() {
      if (quiz.isEnded()) {
        showScores();
      } else {
        var element = document.getElementById("question");
        element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

        var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
          var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
          element.innerHTML = choices[i];
          guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
        }

      }
    };

    function guess() {
      var button = document.getElementById(id);
      button.onclick = function() {
        quiz.guess(guess);
        populate();
      }
    }

    function showScores() {
      var gameOverHtml = "<h1>Result</h1>";
      gameOverHtml += "<h2 id='score'> Your scores: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";
      var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
      element.innerHTML = gameOverHtml;
    }
    var questions = [
      new Question("Which is not an object?", ["Java", "C#", "C++", "C"], "C"),
      new Question("Which is not an object?", ["Java", "C#", "C++", "C"], "C"),
      new Question("Which is not an object?", ["Java", "C#", "C++", "C"], "C"),
      new Question("Which is not an object?", ["Java", "C#", "C++", "C"], "C"),
      new Question("Which is not an object?", ["Java", "C#", "C++", "C"], "C"),
    ];
    var quiz = new Quiz(questions);
    populate();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: The *language* attribute for script elements was deprecated in HTML 4 and was removed long ago.

Answer (score 3):

There are a large number of issues with this application, ranging from missing parameters, to missing functions:

There doesn't seem to be a function called `isEnded` on Quiz.

I assumed it was meant to be when All the Questions have been asked:

```
Quiz.prototype.isEnded = function() {
    return this.questionIndex === this.questions.length;
}
```

`this.questions(this.questionIndex)`. You are passing in an array of Questions.  So this.questions is actually an array.  I suspect you wanted:

```
Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
    return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}
```

You don't really need the inner span, and in fact makes it slightly easier to get the answer out:

```
    <button id="btn0"></button>
    <button id="btn1"></button>
    <button id="btn2"></button>
    <button id="btn3"></button>
```

Changing the rendering choice's section of your Populate to:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
      var element = document.getElementById("btn" + i);
      element.innerHTML = choices[i];
      guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
    }
```

The Guess Function doesn't define the `id` variable, which is missing from the Parameters

```
function guess(id) {
    var button = document.getElementById(id);
    button.onclick = function(event) {
        quiz.guess(this.innerHTML);
        populate();
    }
}
```

When checking the guess, you are incrementing before checking the answer. So at the end, your questionIndex is one larger then the array has questions thus, undefined:

```
Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {      
  if (this.getQuestionIndex().correctAnswer(answer)) {
    this.score++;
  }

  this.questionIndex++;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Quiz</title>
</head>
<style>
  body {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
  }
  
  .grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #cbcbcb;
    box-shadow: 10px 15px 5px #cbcbcb
  }
  
  .grid h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #57636e;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2px 0px border-radius: 50px
  }
  
  .grid #question {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #5a6772
  }
  
  .buttons {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  
  #btn0,
  #btn1,
  #btn2,
  #btn3 {
    background-color: #778897;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #1d3c6a;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 10px 40px 10px 0px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
  }
  
  #progress {
    color: #2b2b2b;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  
  #btn0:hover,
  #btn1:hover,
  #btn2:hover,
  #btn3:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #57636e;
  }
  
  #btn0:focus,
  #btn1:focus,
  #btn2:focus,
  #btn3:focus {
    outline: 0;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div id="quiz">
      <h1>Quiz</h1>
      <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px">

      <p id="question"></p>

      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
        <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
        <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
        <button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
      </div>

      <hr style="margin-top: 50px">
      <footer>
        <p id="progress">Question x of y.</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script language="text/javascript">
    function Quiz(questions) {
      this.score = 0;
      this.questions = questions;
      this.questionIndex = 0;
    }
    Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
      return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
    }
    Quiz.prototype.isIndex = function() {
      return this.questions.length === this.questionIndex;
    }
    
    Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
      if (this.getQuestionIndex().correctAnswer(answer)) {
        this.score++;
      }
      
      this.questionIndex++;
    }
    
    Quiz.prototype.isEnded = function() {
       return this.questionIndex === this.questions.length;
     }
    
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    //Questions.js
    function Question(text, choices, answer) {
      this.text = text;
      this.choices = choices;
      this.answer = answer;
    }
    
    Question.prototype.correctAnswer = function(choice) {
      return choice === this.answer;
    }
    
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    //Apps
    function populate() {
      if (quiz.isEnded()) {
        showScores();
      } else {
        var element = document.getElementById("question");
        element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

        var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
        for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
          var element = document.getElementById("btn" + i);
          element.innerHTML = choices[i];
          guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
        }

      }
    };

    function guess(id) {
      var button = document.getElementById(id);
      button.onclick = function(event) {
        quiz.guess(this.innerHTML);
        populate();
      }
    }

    function showScores() {
      var gameOverHtml = "<h1>Result</h1>";
      gameOverHtml += "<h2 id='score'> Your scores: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";
      var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
      element.innerHTML = gameOverHtml;
    }
    var questions = [
      new Question("Which is not an object?", ["Java", "C#", "C++", "C"], "C"),
      new Question("Which is not an object?", ["Java", "C#", "C++", "C"], "C"),
      new Question("Which is not an object?", ["Java", "C#", "C++", "C"], "C"),
      new Question("Which is not an object?", ["Java", "C#", "C++", "C"], "C"),
      new Question("Which is not an object?", ["Java", "C#", "C++", "C"], "C"),
    ];
    var quiz = new Quiz(questions);
    populate();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's sorted the issue!

Comment: Also, you may want to change language to "type="text/javascript""